# How to migrate user stores and Oauth from 4.5.0 to 5.5.0 WSO2 IS

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am migrating WSO2 Identity server from version 4.5.0 to 5.5.0 using the steps given below,

1. Migrated from 4.5.0 to 5.0.0 given in https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Upgrading+from+a+Previous+Release
2. Then I migrated from 5.0.0 to 5.5.0 by changing the current version to 5.0.0 as per the document https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS550/Upgrading+from+a+Previous+Release

But the primary user stores which were created using ldap and all the Oauth created in 4.5.0 are not migrated. Why ?
Is there any other steps I need to do ?

Comment: which database you are using?

Comment: MSSQL SERVER-2012

Comment: LDAP user store got migrated, Im having issue only with the Oauth